# Get most common value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next table:

```
id value
 1 2
 2 4
 3 2
 4 2
 5 3
```

How I can get most common (common means that the count of 2 is 3, count of 4 is 1 and count of 3 is 1, so common is 2) 'value'? in this case it is '2'?

Comment: Can you explain why it's 2 and not e.g. 3? What defines the sort order to calculate the "most recent" value?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "common" instead of "recent"? Otherwise, I'd say the most recent value is "3", as it has the greatest ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `group by`

```
select value
from the_table
group by value
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```